# Removing Values from Pandas Read Excel

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to read values from an excel and change them to json to use in my API.

I am getting:

```
{"Names":{"0":"Tom","1":"Bill","2":"Sally","3":"Cody","4":"Betty"}}
```

I only want to see the values. What I would like to get is this:

```
{"Names":{"Tom", "Bill", "Sally", "Cody", "Betty"}}
```

I haven't figured out how to remove the numbers before the values.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Names.xlsx')

json_str = df.to_json()

print(json_str)
```

Comment: `{"Names":{"Tom", "Bill", "Sally", "Cody", "Betty"}}` is not valid json

Comment: `df.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your desired result is not valid json.

maybe you can do this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Names.xlsx')
json_str = df.to_json()
temp = json.loads(json_str)
temp['Names'] = list(temp['Names'].values())
print(json.dumps(temp))
```